# Delete from entities' ElementCollections with JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

My entity `User` has a basic collection as such:

```
@ElementCollection
private Set<String> completedQuests = Sets.newHashSet();
```

How can I remove some values from that set *for all/multiple users*? What is the proper JPQL for this pseudoquery?

```
DELETE FROM User.completeQuests
WHERE value IN (:collectionOfValues)
```

(A Hibernate-only alternative, though not preferred, is also welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, native SQL.

```
em
    .createNativeQuery(
        "DELETE FROM user_completedquests " +
        "WHERE completedquests IN (:daily)"
    )
    .setParameter("daily", dailyQuests)
    .executeUpdate();
```

(Haven't tested it yet)